# Running .NET app and DLLs on an Android phone?

Tags: c#, android, dll, mono, porting

I've got a .NET app and some related third party DLLs, that I would like to run on an Android phone. The .NET app is written in C# and the DLLs are fully mananged, although they contain some `unsafe` code and work with DirectX using managed C++. Is it possible to retarget the application to Mono, and run it on the Android OS, considering that I only have a part of the application source code?

Comment: I think you'd be needing Mono for Android.

Comment: Presumably you are using Mono for Android via MonoDevelop? My understanding is that in many *managed* cases, this should basically *just work* as long as the library doesn't use anything that is not available... HOWEVER! the  DirectX code almost certainly **WILL NOT WORK AT ALL** (but feel free to try)

Comment: I'm currently using C# for Windows using VS 2010. I just read up on Mono online and figured it could help.

Comment: DirectX isn't supported on Android.  Everything else that can be compiled by Mono will work.

Comment: @Geotarget you should be able to use the free version of Mono for Android to test it against an emulator. If you think it has potential, the paid version can target your physical device(s) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unsafe  may be bit-twidlling in an OS specific way. I would use reflector to dump out the code and investigate what's it's doing and then see what mono makes of it.

Since it's using DirectX I'd suspect you're probably going to end up down a dead end.

I've looked at the [Mono Libraries](http://www.mono-project.com/Libraries) and [Axiom 3D](http://axiomengine.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) might be a useful abstraction to use if you need to re-engineer the Direct X calls.

Comment: I've analyzed the 3rd party DLLs using reflector, and they contain some code that works with DirectX and uses a lot of pointers etc. This code is probably C++ in a .NET DLL although I don't understand how that works.

Comment: @Geotarget The DirectX stuff won't be supported on Android.

Answer (score 2):

This is either impossible or very close to an Heracles's task.

Consider porting the existing code to Android and re-writing the missing bits.

Comment: I'm up voting this just for the use of the Greek version of the saying.

Comment: By Android, do you mean Java? The *bulk* of this shouldn't need any "porting" at all, thanks to Mono for Android.

Comment: You are right about Mono for Android. I actually meant porting C# to Java. If the part of the code that needs to be rewritten is big, it may be safer to drop .NET altogether and rewrite the whole thing. When doing the migration from pure .NET to Mono, you are bound to meet some inconsistencies. Some porting will be necessary anyhow.